# Need to select a value from table and store it into variable

Tags: c#, sql, selenium

Hello everyone I am currently working on some testing project and I am having a little problem. Using selenium, I need to `SendKey` in specific element but instead of fixed value i need to use value (data) from my database. Can anyone help me with how to retrieve single value from database and store it in a variable so i can use it later.

Thank you and sorry for a noobish question - see code below:

```cs
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
 SqlCommand command;
 SqlDataReader dataReader;
 conn.ConnectionString = "Server=******;Database=****;User ID=sqlserver;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
 string query = "select RequestID, from AutomaticPayment where RequestID ='1230322'";
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
 conn.Open();
 dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
 dt.Load(dataReader);
 driver.FindElement(By.Id("requestID")).SendKeys(VALUE FROM DATABASE);
```

Comment: Ok, what is the problem? You can't retrieve a single value from the database?

Comment: Yup i have no idea how to do it to be honest in visaul studio and store it in variable ( i know select statement in SQL )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditions to limit the result:

**Select data**
    SELECT TOP 1 RequestID FROM AutomaticPayment  // Always returns 1 row

Or

```
SELECT RequestID FROM AutomaticPayment WHERE Id = 123  // Id must be unique to return 1 row
```

And maybe other ways.

**Get value**

```
var value = dt.Rows[0][1];
```

Or

```
var value = dt.Rows[0]["RequestID"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                try
                {
                    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }
                catch(NullReferenceException n)
                {
                    result = "";
                }
            }
```

`ExecuteScaler` gets you the first column of the first row and additional columns are ignored. Use the value from `result` in your `SendKeys()`

Answer (score 0):

From what i worked on with SqlCommand just do the following :

```
int yourId = 0;
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

while(dataReader.Read())
{
    yourId = dataReader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

With that, you should have your value set to the first column of the dataReader. (that is selected thanks to your query, since you are requesting on a specific id, i guess it will return only one column

there is many other type available for Reader : [Reader Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8)

And if you have in the futur many data to collect, use the ORM entity framework, work well for me

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8)

**EDIT :**

Since you are only querying one data, maybe the solution of @work_ishaan is better than mine in this case, check it out.